# resp.cookie doesn't work while using with bcrypt.compare

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I am trying to implant a cookie on the browser after verifying that hashed password and user password in login route is correct.
The code does anything correctly(including generating the token), but when it arrives resp.cookie it doesn't execute it.
(if I am not using bcrypt, the code manage to execute resp.cookie)

here is my code:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, resp) => {
    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let user = await User.find().where({email: email});
    if (user.length > 0) {
        let comparisonResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password);
        if (comparisonResult) {
            let token = auth.generateToken(user[0]);
            console.log(token);
            resp.cookie('auth_token', token);
            resp.send("loggedin");
        } else {
            resp.send("rejected");
        }
    } else {
        resp.send("rejected");
    }
});
```

Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: Does this code works because await can be used only inside async function??

Comment: Does even enter to the first line when receiving `resp.cookie`?

Comment: Have you set app.use(express.cookieParser());??

Comment: yes I 've set app.use express.cookieParser(). and still....